# Scrapy ItemPipeline - "RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future"

Tags: python, scrapy, python-asyncio, motor-asyncio, mongodb-motor

Trying to drop duplicates by counting documents with same url. Using Motor (an async driver for MongoDB) for that purposes.

Here a `process_item` function:

according to the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/coroutines.html#usage)

```
async def process_item(self, item, spider):
        response = self.mangas.count_documents({"url": item.url})
        print(response, 'is future?', futures.isfuture(response)) # explicit type checking
        count = await response # here an exception
        if count:
            raise DropItem(f"Duplicate found of {item}")
        await self.mangas.insert_one(dict(item))
        return item
```

A traceback:

```
is future? True
2022-08-23 22:39:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing *SOME PARSED DATA*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Canald\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\api-abuLimWH-py3.10\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1660, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = current_context.run(gen.send, result)
  File "C:\Users\Canald\Files\VS\HChan\hentai_scrap\pipelines.py", line 48, in process_item
    count = await response
RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future
```

Also tried to use `maybe_deferred_to_future` from `scrapy.utils.defer`, according to [this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#take-screenshot-of-item), but it raises same exception.

Comment: @Alexander For explicit type checking to show here. `self.mangas.count_documents({"url": item.url})` returns a Future object, that stored in `response` variable. Anyway `count = await self.mangas.count_documents({"url": item.url})` raises same exception.

Comment: Is it an `asyncio.Future` or a `concurrent.futures.Future`? They aren't the same thing.

Comment: @dirn `type()` says it is `<class '_asyncio.Future'>`